# Quiz - user submissions into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to achieve: a quiz system with user account and cumulative results table.

Process:

-User sets up an account
-User logs in
-User completes quiz
-Answers go into results table
-Results table displayed

My database structure:

**Table 1: users**

```
user_id  
username
password
email
```

**Table 2: quizzes**

```
quiz_id
title
```

**Table 3: questions**

```
question_id
quiz_id
question
question_notes
```

**Table 4: answers**

```
answer_id
question_id
user_id
answer
answer_notes
```

**Table 5: responses**

```
response_id
quiz_id
user_id
submit_time
```

The questions will be output from Table 3 via a SELECT.

What I am looking for some pointers for is how I can ensure the relationships for each quiz entry is consistent, so when I run the INSERT statements the IDs are consistent (so the "question_id" for Table 3 and Table 4 are the same, for example)

I am thinking I will have 2 INSERT statements for Table 4 and Table 5.  In these insert statements, is there a way to ensure the relationships match?

I am having some trouble visualising how this will work for entering the data into the database, once I've got this figured out I can tackle using the data.

Any pointers to decent tuts or a bit of insight into possible form processing would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function in MySQL ( mysql_insert_id() in PHP ) that will return auto_increment id from last insert query. This will let you keep consistency.

See here for more details:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 0):

[Foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) and [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) enforce [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)...

For example:

**Answers**

```
question_id is a foreign key to question.id
user_id is a foreign key to user.id
(These are set in the table definition)
```

You insert in to answers like so (sloppy pseudocode):

```
begin transaction
int qid = select id from question
int uid = select id from user
insert (qid,uid,...) into answers
commit transaction
```

Comment: This set me in the right direction, I joined up some tables successfully via the table definitions.  Got a bit lost trying to implement this in a proper way. Not to worry, thanks for the info, I've learnt a lot, not enough yet, but a lot :)